# How to monitor/close pending network sessions in a network program

Tags: c, linux, timer, network-programming

I'm writing something like the below(diameter protocol), I need to implement a timer to monitor sessions pending state and terminate them when they exceed some threshold, what is the best way to do this?

Please note that I'm looking for algorithm.

```
Credit-Control Application Related Parameters
Tx timer

When real-time credit-control is required, the credit-control
client contacts the credit-control server before and while the
service is provided to an end user.  Due to the real-time nature
of the application, the communication delays SHOULD be minimized;
e.g., to avoid an overly long service setup time experienced by
the end user.  The Tx timer is introduced to control the waiting
time in the client in the Pending state.  When the Tx timer
elapses, the credit-control client takes an action to the end user
according to the value of the Credit-Control-Failure-Handling AVP
or Direct-Debiting-Failure-Handling AVP.  The recommended value is
10 seconds.
```

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Can you narrow it to a particular problem you are facing?  Can you also reserve code formatting for actual code and not your text description?

Comment: It's not a broad question, It's about how to handle timers in network application to kill timed out sessions. I don't have the code for it, this is why I'm asking. and BTW I'm not looking for code, I'm looking for algorithm. I updated the question.

Comment: What's there to talk about? It's not like there's a specific algorithm. After launching a connection request, wait for its establishment for `X` seconds, and timeout if that time passes. That's really all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a timer at all.

When your application accepts a new connection using e.g. [`accept()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html), you can record the current time using e.g. [`clock_gettime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) (in particular, using the `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` clock, which requires a 2.6.39 or later kernel).

During processing, especially before sending any responses, your code must check that the connection (timestamp) is not too old yet.

While extremely simple to implement, and very precise, the `clock_gettime()` calls aren't particularly fast. That is, it is not a slow call per se -- there is no faster way to get the current time --, it's just that checking the timestamp against current time does require a `clock_gettime()` call every single time, causing potentially a lot of such calls to be generated.

If performance is more important than the accuracy, one could use a timer interrupt. Timer interrupts occur *after* the specified interval; they may be delayed. In other words, while a timer interrupt should never fire *before* the interval has elapsed, they are allowed to fire at any time *afterwards*. Thus, the timeout is not nearly as strict as above.

When the timer elapses, the signal handler sets a connection/timeout-specific flag. Instead of checking the timestamps, your functions verify that the flag is not set yet.

Since timers in Linux are a limited resource (not scarce, just possibly limited to fewer than the number of simultaneous client connections possible) -- the limit is approximately [`getrlimit(RLIMIT_SIGPENDING)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html), something like forty thousand on my machine --, I advise against creating a separate timer for each connection using [`timer_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) or [`timerfd_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html).

Instead, I'd use a realtime signal (`SIGRTMIN+1` for example) and a (high-priority) thread looping on [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html), with the signal blocked in all other threads, maintaining the *next* timeout event. When the `sigwaitinfo()` call returns, it also registers new timeout events; this way, any thread can add a new timeout event by creating a suitable structure, adding it to a chain or an array, then raising the realtime signal. The `siginfo_t` structure (see [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) for definition) tells whether the signal was generated by a timer or raised via e.g. [`sigqueue()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigqueue.2.html).

In general, using timer interrupt is usually the preferred choice, because it has less overhead than repeatedly comparing the timestamps against current time, and most applications don't care if the timeout is a bit late (as long as it is never too early). In particular, a ten second timeout may be 10.0s for one client, 10.1s for another.

It is difficult to say whether the timeout should be exact in your case or not. The spec you quoted seems to emphasize minimal latencies, whereas having an exact timeout (or even the same timeout for all clients) doesn't seem that important. My personal opinion tilts towards using timer interrupts.

Whichever approach you choose for timeout handling, I recommend you design timeout handling into the logic, from the get go. In both cases your code needs to periodically check whether the connection has timed out; one method just compares current time to the original timestamp, the other a flag. As long as you design the timeout checking in, you are less likely to miss any of the places you need to check for timeout condition for robust and reliable operation.

Hope this helps.